# Temporarily disable wifi on Raspberry Pi 3 via terminal

Tags: wifi

I have a rpi3 connected to an ethernet cable and via wireless to a router.  I believe it may be the cause of terrible connectivity while ssh'ing into my pi3 since it lags horrible on some days, not others etc.

How do I temporarily disable the wifi connection from the terminal in order to determine if its a conflict between both adapters being active at the same time or not?

Comment: Could you explain why you need two connections to the same network in the first place?

Answer (score 9):

To turn WiFi off:

```
sudo rfkill block wifi
```

To turn WiFi back on:

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

To check the status of your wireless communication interfaces:

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

Comment: "sudo rfkill block wifi" and "sudo rfkill list all": 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't worried about actually powering off the WiFi radio, you can probably just bring the WiFi's network interface down - "sudo ifconfig wlan0 down"

Comment: Before you do "sudo ifconfig wlan0 down", do me a favor and do "sudo ifconfig wlan0 up" and let me know the result. Please. "

Comment: After "sudo ifconfig wlan0 down" and "sudo ifconfig wlan0": wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:f6:6c:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1523  bytes 113109 (110.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 995  bytes 161281 (157.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want to disable WiFi at boot, in your /boot/ (or /boot/firmware/ ) "config.txt" file add or uncomment the line "dtoverlay=pi3-disable-wifi"  Note that this may be simply "dtoverlay=disable-wifi" in newer configurations.

To reenable wifi, comment out the line with a leading hash (octothorpe) symbol. (a "#")

[ I use 'mcedit' as my preferred editor.  Others may use vi, ed, vim, nano, or etc...  For guidance on how to edit system configuration files: See other documents. Or RTFM. ]

Comment: Why not simply use `rfkill block all`? No reboot needed.

Comment: @Dougie  Because some of us are neat-nicks.  No WiFi means you can remove all the WiFi associated packages.  Like 'rfkill' as it's no longer needed.